# How to get reference to current Active window?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to get reference to currently Active window. For example, 1
Window above an application, how could I determine which
one is currently active?

Comment: Please provide some additional details.  For example: 
Are you dealing with an AIR App and multiple native windows?  Are you dealing with a browser based app and using the PopUpManager?  How do you define which 'window' is active? Does something inside it have focus?  Or is it merely the window above everything else?

Comment: I am working on AIR app and sometimes multiple window comes on main app. No I have not used PopUpManager to open these window, I simply used window.open() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer on my own. See the following code to get the active window.

```
var activeWindow:NativeWindow = mx.core.Application.application.nativeApplication.activeWindow;
var parent:Sprite = (activeWindow.stage.getChildAt(0) as WindowedSystemManager).document as Sprite;
```